# Regex Match word between quotes in specific variable

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am new to regular expressions and I am trying to do the following:

```
LET CustomerName='test';
or
LET CustomerName = 'test';
or
let CustomerName = 'test';
```

I have this line and I would like to change the test word into something else. So I found this expression:

`(?<=LET CustomerName='')[^'']*`

And that works for my first example, but I would like to make it more robust so it can also recognize the second line.

I found this code to replace something between quotes but I would like to only change the value between quotes in the specific line.

```
(?<=(["']))(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?(?=\1)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use

```
(?<=CustomerName\s*=\s*')[^']+(?=')
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=CustomerName\s*=\s*')` Positive lookbehind, assert directly to the left `CustomerName` followed by `=` between optional whitspace chars
- `[^']+` match 1+ times any char except `'` using a negated character class
- `(?=')` Positive lookahead, assert `'` directly to the right

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dCustomerName%5cs*%3d%5cs*%27%29%5b%5e%27%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%27%29&i=LET+CustomerName%3d%27test%27%3b%0d%0aor%0d%0aLET+CustomerName+%3d+%27test%27%3b%0d%0aor%0d%0alet+CustomerName+%3d+%27test%27%3b&r=%5bReplacement%5d) *(click on the **Context** tab to see the replacements)*

Example

```
$strings = @("LET CustomerName='test';", "LET CustomerName = 'test';", "let CustomerName = 'test';")
$strings -replace "(?<=CustomerName\s*=\s*')[^']+(?=')","[replacement]"
```

Ouput

```
LET CustomerName='[replacement]';
LET CustomerName = '[replacement]';
let CustomerName = '[replacement]';
```

---

If you want to match either a single or a double quote at each side, and allow matching for example a double quote between the single quotes, you can use a capture group for one of the chars `(["'])`.

Then continue matching all that is not equal to what is captured using a backreference `\1` until to can assert what is capture to the right.

```
(?<=CustomerName\s*=\s*(["']))(?:(?!\1).)+(?=\1)
```

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dCustomerName%5cs*%3d%5cs*%28%5b%22%27%5d%29%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5c1%29.%29%2b%28%3f%3d%5c1%29&i=LET+CustomerName%3d%27test%27%3b%0d%0aLET+CustomerName+%3d+%27test%27%3b%0d%0alet+CustomerName+%3d+%27test%27%3b%0d%0aLET+CustomerName%3d%22test%22%3b%0d%0aLET+CustomerName+%3d+%22test%22%3b%0d%0alet+CustomerName+%3d+%22test%22%3b%0d%0aLET+CustomerName%3d%22test%27%3b%0d%0aLET+CustomerName+%3d+%27test%22%3b%0d%0alet+CustomerName+%3d+%22t%27est%22%3b%0d%0alet+CustomerName+%3d+%27t%22e%22st%27%3b&r=%5bReplacement%5d)

Or allowing escaped single and double quotes using atomic groups:

```
(?<=CustomerName\s*=\s*(["']))(?>(?!\1|\\).)*(?>\\\1(?>(?!\1|\\).)*)*(?=\1)
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dCustomerName%5cs*%3d%5cs*%28%5b%22%27%5d%29%29%28%3f%3e%28%3f!%5c1%7c%5c%5c%29.%29*%28%3f%3e%5c%5c%5c1%28%3f%3e%28%3f!%5c1%7c%5c%5c%29.%29*%29*%28%3f%3d%5c1%29&i=LET+CustomerName%3d%27test%27%3b%0d%0aLET+CustomerName+%3d+%27test%27%3b%0d%0alet+CustomerName+%3d+%27test%27%3b%0d%0aLET+CustomerName%3d%22te%5c%22st%22%3b%0d%0aLET+CustomerName+%3d+%22test%22%3b%0d%0alet+CustomerName+%3d+%22test%22%3b%0d%0aLET+CustomerName%3d%22test%27%3b%0d%0aLET+CustomerName+%3d+%27test%22%3b%0d%0alet+CustomerName+%3d+%22t%27est%22%3b%0d%0alet+CustomerName+%3d+%27t%22e%22st%27%3b%0d%0aLET+CustomerName%3d%27te%5c%27st%27%3b&r=%5bReplacement%5d)

Comment: lookbehind is not supported in all regexp flavours and some only support fix length expressions. In Powershell this is fine. To include the leading `LET` or `let` you could add `(?:let|LET)` od `[Ll][Ee][Tt]`

Comment: @bw_üezi That is why I used the quantifiers in the lookbehind because it is supported.

Comment: @bw_üezi: See the .net-demo at the end of the answer - +1.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Is it also possible to check between '' if it is an empty string? 
LET CustomerName='';